# ERROR : Single-row subquery returns more than one row. I am trying to add data in column

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a temp table and want to insert values in the table using select statements but when I run this query I am getting the above error. Is there any efficient way.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MANAGER_DATA;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE MANAGER_DATA (
  WORKER_ID VARCHAR, ACCOUNT VARCHAR,
  ACTIVE Boolean, REPORTING_NAME VARCHAR,
  BUSINESS_TITLE VARCHAR, MANAGER_WORKER_ID VARCHAR, 
  MANAGER_REPORTING_NAME Text, MANAGER_OF_MANAGER_ID VARCHAR,
  MANAGER_OF_MANAGER_NAME VARCHAR);

INSERT INTO MANAGER_DATA ( 
  SELECT WORKER_ID,
    ACCOUNT, 
    ACTIVE, 
    REPORTING_NAME, 
    BUSINESS_TITLE, 
    MANAGER_WORKER_ID,
    (
      SELECT
        A.REPORTING_NAME 
      FROM ALL_ASSOCIATES_V AS A
      INNER JOIN  ALL_ASSOCIATES_V AS B 
        ON A.MANAGER_WORKER_ID = B.WORKER_ID), 
    (
      SELECT B.MANAGER_WORKER_ID 
      FROM ALL_ASSOCIATES_V AS A 
      INNER JOIN  ALL_ASSOCIATES_V AS B 
        ON A.MANAGER_WORKER_ID = B.WORKER_ID),
     NULL 
    FROM ALL_ASSOCIATES_V
  );

SELECT * FROM MANAGER_DATA;
```

Comment: Those sub-selects in the SELECT, really should be moved to normal joins with some method to limit the number of result, given the error is telling you, you have duplicate data on the joins

Comment: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` seems like MySQL... are you really using Microsoft SQL Server here (i.e.: the `sql-server` tag)?

Comment: Thanks Simeon actually was able to solve the query because of your help thanks.